# How to keep CPU usage level low in Socket long connection

Tags: java, android, sockets

Sorry for my pool English.
I have a javaFx application which is need to connect to many Socket Servers(more than 40) which are starting in android phones.
When connect to a server I make a thread to hold the long connection,every 600ms the server send the SCREENSHOT(binary) to my application.
The javaFx application can't be the server.
Here is part of the code:

```
while (ScreenMonitorService.isConnectionAll()){
Future<Image> f = ThreadPoolUtil.getThreadPool().submit(new Callable<Image>() {
  @Override
  public Image call() throws Exception {
       return readImage(inputStream, outputStream);
    }
  });
Image fxImage = f.get();
Platform.runLater(()->{
    device.getImageView().setImage(fxImage);
});


//what readImage do
private synchronized Image readImage(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
try {
        Thread.sleep(700);<==== This is the now solution for high cpu performtion , but it doesn't work
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error("=====> error", e);
    }
    int fileLen = readInt(inputStream);
    int readLength = fileLen;
    int tempLength = 0;
    int n;
    byte[] bt = new byte[readLength];
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((n = inputStream.read(bt,0,readLength)) > 0) {
        tempLength += n;
        readLength = tempLength + n > fileLen ? fileLen - tempLength : readLength;
        bout.write(bt,0,n);
    }
    ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(bout.toByteArray());
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bin);
    Image fxImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image,null);
    writeInt(outputStream,1);
    return fxImage;
 }
```

I know that is the busy-wating which make the bad cpu performance.
I have used nio|notify/wait|blockqueue to try to solve the problem,but failed.
May be someone can give me some suggestions to solve this,Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually .... you are not busy waiting, and the `sleep` is not the cause of your problems.

What you really ought to do is to *profile* the code to see where it is spending most of its time.  I *suspect* that it is actually in these two calls:

```
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bin);
    Image fxImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null);
```

In other words, I suspect that most of the CPU is going in converting the images.  If that is the case, then you need to figure out a way to do less image processing.

It is also possible that this is a GC-related problem, but profiling would provide evidence for that too.

---

I notice that you are buffering the entire file in memory before processing it.  That could make things slower.  You could avoid that by wrapping the `InputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream` and passing the `BIS` to `ImageIO.read`.  But I don't think the double-handling of the bytes is the main problem.

Comment: The converting cost about 200 ms.

Comment: Sorry, the converting cost is 20ms

Comment: So if you have profiled the code ... where is most of the time *actually* going?

Comment: ReadInt() cost most time,(about 200ms),which is to read four times to get the data's length.The sever send data per 600ms.So,I think maybe read too fast cost the cpu perfomance so

Comment: Erm ... that 200ms is not CPU usage.  It is actually idle time because you are waiting for the server.  You need to measure CPU time, not elapsed time.